# 'from . import XYZ'

Tags: python

I've ran into the above line. I'm searching a codebase, [gem5](https://github.com/gem5/gem5) to find where occurences of `m5.defines` are coming from. Inside a directory named `m5`, in the `__init__.py`, I see `from . import defines`, but there is no file or directory named `defines` there. `grep` also yields nothing useful.

Where is this coming from?

Comment: Incidentally if you're still on `grep -R`, you really need to check out `ripgrep` (or `ag` or `pt` or doubtless any of the others)

Comment: And what benefit do they pose @2e0byo?

Comment: Speed.  Sub 1s searches on large codebases.  Try one out :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is generated [here](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/48a40cf2f5182a82de360b7efa497d82e06b1631/src/SConscript#L620-L622):

```py
env.Command('python/m5/defines.py', ToValue(dict(build_env)),
            MakeAction(makeDefinesPyFile, Transform("DEFINES", 0)))
PySource('m5', 'python/m5/defines.py')
```

Directly above the import you mention is logic which presumably exists to detect if this file has in fact been generated.

Comment: So `from . import XYZ` searches the current directory for the file, but in this case, the file is dynamically generated.

Comment: @user129393192 specifically the file is generated once, in the build step.  `from .` searches the current *package*, which for historic reasons is slightly less useful than the current dir in python---it will fail if you invoke the file directly.

Comment: Interesting, because even though I've `compiled`/built the program, it is not there. I suppose it only generates it when I **run** the program.

Comment: ah fair, I really know very little about this program---I don't even know what it is.  I just wanted to clarify that I the file is generated elsewhere (in what a cursory glance suggested was build logic), and there's nothing magic going on---just a confusingly large project.